# two way data binding with Angular 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Basically what my problem is that I have a input field and text area like so:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your URL*" id="userURL" ng-model = "usermodel"/><br />
<textarea id="final">{{usermodel}}</textarea><br />
```

So my problem is that text will be manipulated via controller, and I want the user to be able to type into the field WITHOUT the textarea refreshing.

For example:

```
controller: {
textareaoutoutput = "hi ..... How are you";}

textarea: hi {{usermodel}} how are you? <br>
input field: john
```

BUT when I type into the field, "Hi how are you" gets removed, and only the text field input is shown. I would like it so that the "Hi how are you" is fixed and will not change while the user can enter and still see it add instantly.

I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

inside controller :

```js
$scope.textVal = " hi "+ $scope.usermodel + " how are you?"
```

```html
<textarea id="final">{{textVal}}</textarea><br />
```

I hope you can understand it always try to function for the manipulate string

or

```html
<textarea id="final">Hi {{usermodel}} how are you!</textarea><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

hm, I am not sure if this will work. 
the controller is going to output text to the text area, but I want the angular expression tags {{x}} to be in the middle of the the document will be outputting

Maybe this example will be better

textarea:

```
TEXTA + {{angular expression}} + TEXTB
```

is it possible to output data to text a and text b and have a user still add something to the {{x}} without refreshing the textarea